# Thread memory is not released

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, struts, java-threads

I have a issue like, I have written the DownloadAction(for download a document) in struts after that i am forwarding request to some jsp.

Here the snippet.

```
public class DownloadAction extends AbstractAction {

public ActionForward protectedExecute(AXXMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws RBACPermissionDeniedException,
            NoSuchObjectException {
// written some code for download a file.
return findForward(mapping, "download");
}
}

struts-config.xml
------------------
<action
                path="/download"
                type="DownloadAction"
                scope="request">
      <forward name="download" path="/jsp/success.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Here download went fine with no failure, but it is not forwarding the request to success.jsp.

In this case for downloading a document jvm took around 400mb of heap memory, but it is not releasing memory. Even I ran GC(Garbage collector) Manualy then also it is not releasing the memory. I have used jconsole to see the heap memory.

Any suggestions please..:)

Comment: `// written some code for download a file.` actually could be relevant

Comment: Try creating a heap dump (e.g. using jconsole) and analyzing it (e.g. using Eclipse MAT) to find out who's still holding a reference to the memory. Running GC doesn't make much sense if the memory is not elligible for collection, i.e. there's still some reference to the object(s) held by some live thread.

Comment: @Thomas I have created dump like : jmap -dump:file=D:\temp\heapdumps\dump.bin 1234<jboss process id> after that i dont know how to analyse it..

Comment: @RagalaPurushotham Yes you could do that as well, as I indicated there are multiple ways to create and analyze a heap dump. ;)

Comment: @Thomas still y it is holding the reference. once the response is committed means, thread has to go dead state right.

Comment: There might be another place that's holding the reference. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell and even if you post it we might still miss something. That's why I suggested analyzing the heap dump's dominator tree (which threads and objects keep the memory alive?).